# First number in array not transferring to new array correctly

Tags: arrays, c, cs50

I am writing a program to break numbers in an array into their digits then store those digits in a new array. I have two problems:

1. It does not display the first number in the array (2) when transferred to the second array, and I am not entirely sure why.
2. The array may contain 0's, which would break my current `for` loop. Is there another way to implement a `for` loop to only run for as many numbers are stored in a array without knowing how big the array is?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Setting an array equal to test variables
    int sum[50] = { 2, 6, 3, 10, 32, 64 };

    int i, l, k = 0, sumdig[10], dig = 0;
    // Runs for every digit in array sum, increases size of separate variable k every time loop runs
    for (i = 0; sum[i] > 0; i++ && k++)
    {
        sumdig[k] = sum[i] % 10;
        dig++;
        sum[i] /= 10;

        // If statement checks to see if the number was two digits
        if (sum[i] > 0)
        {
            // Advancing a place in the array
            k++;
            // Setting the new array position equal to the
            sumdig[k] = sum[i] % 10;
            dig++;
        }
    }

    // For testing purposes - looking to see what digits have been stored
    for (l = 0; l < dig; l++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", sumdig[l]);
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
6
3
0
1
2
3
4
6
0
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Solution:

> It does not display the first number in the array (2) when transferred to the second array

changes `i++ && k++`  into `i++,k++`

---

> Is there another way to implement a for loop to only run for as many numbers are stored in an array

There are many different ways but here is some to illustrate it in a few different scenarios:

**1. The array length is known and fixed:**
Let the compiler automatically allocate the array for you. And then `for(i=0; i<6; i++)`

**2. Able to calc the array length:**
Then count the number of elements when initializing the array into a varible. Then just `for(i=0; i<SizeCount; i++)`

**3. Not-able to know array size for some reason:**
It is rare but, in that case, you can pre-set a stop criteria i.e. -1 or some other flag so that you can stop when it reaches the terminator i.e. set or pre-set all other values of `sum` to be -1. Then you can `while(sum[i] != -1)` This is how string lengths work in C, either with NULL termination (string end with the number 0 or value `NULL`) or, with input, the line break character `\n` indicating a termination.

---

##### DEMO

Here is a demo of full code with some explanation:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){    
    int sum[] = {2, 6, 3, 10, 32, 64};  // compiler is smart enough know the size

    int i, k = 0, sumdig[10], dig = 0;
    // Runs for every digit in array sum, increases size of seperate variable k everytime loop runs
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(sum)/sizeof(int); i++, k++){
        sumdig[k] = sum[i] % 10;
        dig++;
        sum[i] /= 10;
        // If statement checks to see if the number was two digits
        if (sum[i] > 0)
        {
            // Advancing a place in the array
            k++;
            // Setting the new array position equal to the
            sumdig[k] = sum[i] % 10;
            dig++;
        }
    }

    // For testing purposes - looking to see what digits have been stored
    for(i = 0; i < dig; i++){
        printf("%i\n", sumdig[i]);
    }
}
```

- Compile and run

  gcc -Wall demo.c -o demo

  ./demo
- Output

  ```
  2
  6
  3
  0
  1
  2
  3
  4
  6
  ```